# root "su - <user>" got permission denied (Ignored)

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, users, su, postgresql

Got permission denied when switching user from root to postgres.
No issue switching from root to ubuntu.

```
root@node-01:~# su - postgres
su: Permission denied
(Ignored)
postgres@node-01:~$ logout
root@node-01:~# su - ubuntu
ubuntu@nodeg-01:~$
```

Here is the /etc/passwd and /etc/group entries:

`postgres:x:998:998::/home/postgres:/bin/bash`

`postgres:x:998:`

Comment: Does the postgres user have an  "su" in its shell init files?

Comment: There's no shell init files for postgres user.

Comment: What happens if you remove the login option shortcut (`-`)?

Comment: same error without (-)

Comment: Possibly PAM is interfering?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by adding the user to `/etc/security/access.conf`.

Comment: This did not solve my issue.  Is there a service you need to restart after changing this?

Answer (score -5):

While logged in as the root user type:

"**chmod 775 /bin/su**"

This changes the permissions for **owner** and **groups** to 7 (**r,w,x**) and the permissions of other users to 5 (**r,x**) of the '**su**' binary file in the **/bin** directory.

Comment: tell me if this works or not

Comment: same error

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 40128 May 16  2017 su`

Comment: Do not do this.  That breaks `su` on most systems.  `su` is normally owned by root:root and permission 4755